# Waitpid and synchronization issues

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, process, posix

I created a simple `Process` class that mimics `std::thread`. It is supposed to work on linux only.

```
struct Process
{
    Process(/*...*/) { /* fork + join, initialize m_pid */ }
    ~Process() { assert(!joinable()); }

    bool joinable() const { return m_pid != 0; }

    void join()
    {
       assert (joinable());
       int status;
       waitpid(m_pid, &status, 0);
       m_pid = 0;
    }
private:
    std::atomic<pid_t> m_pid;
};
```

I have an additional requirement: I need to be able to stop the process from another thread.

For example:

```
Process p(/* ... */ );

Thread 1:
     p.join();

Thread 2:
     p.interrupt();
```

How can I implement a thread-safe `Process:interrupt`? My first idea is something like this:

```
 void Process::interrupt()
 {
     if (m_pid)
        kill(m_pid, SIGTERM);
 }
```

Unfortunately I am not sure that this works, because if `interrupt` is called between `waitpid` and `m_pid = 0` in `join()` then I am killing a non-existent process, or worse a completely unrelated process that happen to have the same pid as the old one.

Swapping the `m_pid = 0` and `waitpid` statements in `join()` would make the interruption quite useless, since you can expect that the first thread will spend most of its time inside waiting for the child process to terminate.

So what I need is a `waitpid` that waits for the child process termination but keeps the child process in a zombie state, so that no process with the same pid can be spawn in the meantime.

Is there such a thing or any other solution?

Comment: You can just use a lock

Comment: @Dani err... how? If I lock the entire `waitpid` + `m_pid = 0` section then interrupt will wait until the process has terminated.. that is not what I want.  Ideally i need something like `pthread_cond_wait` where you can pass a lock to the function and it will be atomically locked when the `waitpid` returns.

Comment: You can interrupt the waitpid, kill the process and resume the waitpid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, a blocking `waitpid(m_pid, ...); m_pid = 0` in one thread of control and a `kill(m_pid, ...)` in another will race.  Adding a mutex won't help for the reason you indicated — the waiter must wait *and* update some global information, but the killer must be allowed to (indirectly) interrupt the waiting.

(I'm going to ignore the part about mimicking `std::thread`, which does not, for instance, support interruption.)

Instead, you can rely on an inherited [`pipe`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pipe.html), and make sure the child process inherits the write-end of the pipe, leaving the parent with the read-end.  That read-end will indicate EOF when the child terminates, but the external resource (the zombie process entry) will remain until explicitly reaped.  This method isn't foolproof, since the child might fork or exec or otherwise close or pass along its write-end fd unexpectedly.

As an aside, there are more complex solutions you could engineer.  For instance, you could spawn a single secret thread to `waitpid` and `kill` the child process, and your `interrupt` method could then interrupt that thread with a real-time signal.  You could take over handling SIGCHLD for the entire parent process, too.  These are heavyweight and error-prone, though.

Comment: I'll go with the pipe. I need to read the child process' stdout anyway